# Functions file mods and CPU

Tags: functions, database

Will adding code similar to what I've pasted below to the functions.php theme file slow down a Wordpress site or effect CPU? (Thank You)

```
function remove_menu_items() {
  global $menu;
  $restricted = array(__('Links'), __('Comments'), __('Media'),
  __('Plugins'), __('Tools'), __('Users'));
  end ($menu);
  while (prev($menu)){
    $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
    if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){
      unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope or Not really or Not noticeably.